# Fetching firestore data into a custom object

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, google-cloud-firestore

Toast under onSucces method is working but  Toast outside onSucces  is not working is says

"java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.collegecommune.User.getName()' on a null object reference"

I am trying to fetch current user data from the firestore and store it in custom class User.
I wanted to **store documentSnapshot.toObject(User.class)** in **currentUser**.

```
static FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
static FirebaseUser cUser = auth.getCurrentUser();
public static User currentUser;
private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();     


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    fetchProfile();
    //        currentUser = new FirebaseInteract(this).fetchProfile(cUser);

    setupToolbar();
    navItemSelected();
    //        role = currentUser.getRole();
    //        Toast.makeText(this, currentUser.getName() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.home);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new HomeFragment()).commit();
    }

}

public void fetchProfile() {
    db.collection("users").document(cUser.getEmail()).get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                    currentUser = documentSnapshot.toObject(User.class);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, currentUser.getName() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, currentUser.getSemester() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Successfully fetched user profile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, currentUser.getName() + "22", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, currentUser.getSemester() + "22", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

**I have recently tried this code:**
it also does'nt work.

```
 public void fetchProfile(String email) {
    final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    dialog.setMessage("Fetching your profile...");
    dialog.show();

    db.collection("users").document(email).get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                    User user1 = documentSnapshot.toObject(User.class);
                    Toast.makeText(activity, user1.getEmail() + " 00", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    MainActivity.setCurrentUser(user1);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(onFailureListener);
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't appear to be formatted correctly. Would you like the edit the question and correct it?

Comment: Your code is not properly formatted. Please correct that. By looking at current implementation if your profile fetching fails your currentUser object will be null and therefore the error.

Answer (score 2):

By looking at current implementation I can say  - your `onSuccess` call is asynchronous & it'll take time to fetch data & update `currentUser` object . 
Till that time your toast which is outside the `onSuccess` block will execute & try to fetch data from `currentUser` object which will be **null** at that point of time.. therefore it throws `nullPointetException`

Comment: Can you help me with this. To make it synchronous.

Comment: I'm creating a blog kind of app. I wanted to fetch currently logged in user data from firestore so that i can fill his details in profile fragment. Please help me with that.                        Thank you in advance.

Comment: You'll have to do everything related to user profile after fetching data from firebase only. So, you'll have to write that in onSuccess. Till the loading time you can show loader or some other effects like 'shimmer effect' on screen & don't forget to handle failed case too.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but in some cases i will require user profile data to make decisions that's why i wanted to store user profile data into static User object in MainActivity.

Comment: You can keep that functionality blocked by showing some loading placeholder and then showing your UI after success.

Comment: Also, please mark the answer as correct if it solves your problem.